# Kryo - Error when serializing/deserializing JComboBox

Tags: serialization, jcombobox, kryo

I'm fairly new to Kryo so forgive me if I've made a silly mistake.... I have read the manual, and I think I understand generally how Kryo serializes, but I'm having trouble deserializing a JComboBox.

First, I tried this:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("/tempTest/newTest.kr"));
JComboBox objectToWrite = new JComboBox();       
kryo.writeObject(output, objectToWrite);
output.flush();
output.close();
```

then read...

```
Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream("/tempTest/newTest.kr"));
JComboBox cbox = kryo.readObject(input, JComboBox.class);
```

Doing this generates a "missing no-arg constructor" exception. So I set the fallback instantiator strategy:

```
((DefaultInstantiatorStrategy) kryo.getInstantiatorStrategy()).setFallbackInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
```

However, now I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton.<init>()V from class javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButtonConstructorAccess
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButtonConstructorAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy$1.newInstance(Kryo.java:1193)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1061)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:547)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:523)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:116)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)
at T2SaveLoad.saveLoad(T2SaveLoad.java:112)
at T2SaveLoad.main(T2SaveLoad.java:40)
```

I'm not sure exactly what is happening, can anyone help?

Also, how is the instantiation strategy chosen by kryo? Does each serializer have a different instantiator strategy, or does kryo just have a default and a fallback for all objects it deserializes?

What if you do:

```
kryo.register(JComboBox.class, new JavaSerializer());
```

(which does in fact serialize/deserialize without any errors) - native java deserialization doesn't call the constructor (apart from the no-arg one in the first superclass that doesn't implement serializable), but if you haven't told kryo to set the instantiator strategy to StdInstantiatorStrategy(), does it still try to use a constructor? or does the fact that it is using its JavaSerializer make it use some other instantiation strategy? (which would perhaps make the instantiation strategy serializer-specific?

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't!!